# Why exclude node_modules from being transpiled by Babel?

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader

I'm using Webpack and Babel for a project. I installed `babel-loader` in order to include Babel in my build process. Most of the examples I see online of `babel-loader` use the following configuration in the webpack config file:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
```

My question is, why would we want to exclude `node_modules` from being transpiled by Babel? I know that the documentation says that excluding it will speed up the bundling process. However, if node_modules contains dependencies that are needed for my app to work, shouldn't those dependencies also be converted by Babel? Let's say that I want to transpile my app to use ES5 code, and node_modules contains libraries that are using ES6+. It seems like node_modules should also be included in the files that Babel processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages inside node_modules are likely already built, minified and targeted to ES3, there is no need for Babel to further transpile them.

In a case whereby you import a package and it's in ES6, Webpack automatically builds a dependency graph internally and will detect such package and transpile it to your desired target (ES5) using Babel.

You don't want to let Babel transpile all of the files that reside at node_modules folder (possibly, thousands of files), that's resource-intensive and it'll take a longer time.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I do agree that transpiling node_modules would be intensive. It's good to know that webpack will take care of any "outlier" packages that may be ES6+.

Comment: Saying that "it's of no use" is incorrect -- transpiling `node_modules` would be incredibly useful, as it would allow package authors to ship nothing but modern JS to NPM and consumers can choose which ES they'd like to target. The problem with shipping ES3 is that there's no good way to transpile it up, and this creates massive bundles as they're filled to the brim with polyfills and verbose JS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I have edited the answer accordingly.